# Spring Security UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter: How to access Request after a failed login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am implementing a login page using Angular 7 and Spring Boot and I am with an issued processing a failed login. Basically I want to lock for a specific amount of time the login after X login attempt failures.

HttpSecurity configuration

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("#### Configuring Security ###");
        JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/rest/users/authenticate");//this override the default relative url for login: /login

        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/", "/rest/helloworld/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and()
            .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter);
```

To process the login i created a Filter

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;

    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            UserDto credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue((request.getInputStream()), UserDto.class);            
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    credentials.getUserName(),
                    credentials.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //sucessfull authentication stuff
    }


    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Authentication failed");

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage("access_denied", "Wrong email or password.");
        String jsonObject = JSONUtil.toJson(errorMessage);

        //processing authentication failed attempt
        UserDto credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue((request.getInputStream()), UserDto.class);
        AuthenticationService authenticationService = Application.getApplicationContext().getBean(AuthenticationService.class);
        int numFailedAttemptLogin = authenticationService.authenticationFailedAttempt(credentials.getUserName());

        response.setStatus(403);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(jsonObject);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        //super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
}
```

The login is working fine with no issues. My problem is with the **unsuccessfulAuthentication** method. When the user enters bad credentials, a BadCredentials exception is raised and **unsuccessfulAuthentication**method is call. Here i need to access again to the request form to extract the username and process the *authentication failed attempt* and I am getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

This is because inside the *attemptAuthentication* method the request inputstream is read and obviously closed.

How can i access request body information inside the **unsuccessfulAuthentication**?

I tried SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() but it is null due the authentication failure.

Does anyone have any idea?

Best Regards

Comment: No you don't. Don't override/implement the `unsuccessfulAuthentication` instead create an `ApplicationListener` which listens to `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` events (or specific subclasses). Which implement the logic. That way you have the `Authentication` already and no need to read it again.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked

Answer (score 6):

After following **[M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)** suggestion i was able to create a component that listens specific Exceptions:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
        logger.info(String.format("Event types: %s", applicationEvent.getClass()));
        if (applicationEvent instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
            String username = ((AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) applicationEvent).getAuthentication().getName();
            if (applicationEvent instanceof AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent) {
                logger.info(String.format("User %s failed to login", username));
                //this.handleFailureEvent(username, event.getTimestamp());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This approach is using Exceptions to drive what to do in specific scenarios. I was able to achieve something similar keep using my **JWTAuthenticationFilter** like this

```
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            UserDto credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue((request.getInputStream()), UserDto.class);
            try {
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        credentials.getUserName(),
                        credentials.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
                );
            } catch (BadCredentialsException bce) {
                try {
                    handleBadCredentials(credentials, response);
                    throw bce;
                } catch (LockedException le) {
                    handleUserLocked(credentials, response);
                    throw le;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Authentication failed");

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        response.getWriter().print(authException.getLocalizedMessage());
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

Thak you all for your time and help, much appreciated.